# Let $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$. How to prove $F(\alpha)$ is a finite extension over $F(\beta)$ as $\beta$ being in $F(\alpha)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading a book: A First course in Abstract algebra by John B. Fraleigh. There is a corollary 31.7 states : if $E$ is an extension field of $F$, $\alpha \in  E$ is algebraic over $F$, and $\beta \in F(\alpha)$, then $\deg(\beta, F)$ divides $\deg(\alpha, F)$.

It prove the corollary by claiming $F \leq F(\beta) \leq F(\alpha)$, however is not enough. we need further show that $F(\alpha)$ is a finite extension over $F(\beta)$.

Anyone can help me?  be greatly appreciated

Comment: It follows via a Linear Algebra argument. $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, i.e., $F(\alpha)$ is a finite extension over $F$ already, i.e., it is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space. Thus, it is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F(\beta)$, as any (finite) base of $F(\alpha)$ over $F$ is also a set of generators of $F(\alpha)$ over $F(\beta)$ - except that they don't need to be linearly independent anymore.

Comment: Yes，your explanation is very clear. I see , thank you